# Creating a game in javascript- allocating correct answers

Tags: javascript, css

I am making a pretty simple game, in which you have to select the correct animal to match the animal print which is shown.

I need to allocate the correct print with the correct animal so the score adds up correctly. Unsure of how to go about doing this and would appreciate any help that is given.

here's the code.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function randSort (a,b) {return Math.random() - 0.5}

        var questions = [
            {text: " What animal is this?", img: "AnimalPrints/1.jpg", answers: ["Cheetah", "Tiger", "Ladybird"], ans: },
            {text: " What animal is this one?", img: "AnimalPrints/2.jpg", answers: ["Elephant", "Giraffe", "Snake"], ans: "Giraffe"},
            {text: "What animal is this one please?", img: "AnimalPrints/3.jpg", answers: ["Bumblebee", "Tiger", "Lady bird"], ans: "Bumblebee"}
        ];

        var correctCount = 0;
        var currentQ = 0;

        function select(nr) {
            if (nr == questions[currentQ].ans)
            {
                correctCount++;
                document.getElementById('display').innerHTML= "You win"
            }
            else
            {
                document.getElementById('display').innerHTML= "You lose"
            }
            document.getElementById('display').innerHTML += "<p>Score: "+ correctCount;

            // if its the last one
            nextQ();
        }

        function showQ() {
            document.getElementById('questionText').innerHTML = questions[currentQ].text;

            document.getElementById('animalPrint').src = questions[currentQ].img;

            newhtml = "";
            for (var i = 0; i< questions[currentQ].answers.length; i++)
            {
                newhtml+= "<button onclick = 'select(" + i + ")'>"+ questions[currentQ].answers[i] + "</button>";
            }
            document.getElementById('alloptions').innerHTML = newhtml;
        }

        function nextQ(){
            if (currentQ < questions.length-1)
            {
                currentQ++;
                showQ();
            }
        }

        window.onload =init;

        function init()
        {
            correctCount = 0;
            questions.sort(randSort);
            currentQ = 0;
            showQ();

        }

    </script>
    <title> Game_page</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="gamepage_css.css">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        /*
                        document.write("<img src = \ "" + Math.floor 1 + Math.random() * 10) +
                        ".jpg\" />");

                        document.write("<img src = \"" + Math.floor 1 + Math.random() * )
        */
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id=main>
        <button id="nextbutton" onclick="nextQ();"></button></a>
        <div id="questionText"> Testing</div>
        <div id="animal">
            <img id="animalPrint" src="AnimalPrints/1.jpg">
        </div>
        <div id="alloptions">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="display">Output</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not sure what you're asking.  Can you simplify your question to only include relevant bits of code?

Comment: Sorry I phrased it terribly... I need the computer to link the correct awnser with the correct animal print so the score adds up correctly.. For example click 'cheetah' when the cheetah print is presented and one point is added.. at the moment, it is not recognising the correct awnser..

Comment: Heres the part of the code i used.. function randSort (a,b) {return Math.random() - 0.5}

        var questions = [
            {text: " What animal is this?", img: "AnimalPrints/1.jpg", answers: ["Cheetah", "Tiger", "Ladybird"], ans: },
            {text: " What animal is this one?", img: "AnimalPrints/2.jpg", answers: ["Elephant", "Giraffe", "Snake"], ans: "Giraffe"},
            {text: "What animal is this one please?", img: "AnimalPrints/3.jpg", answers: ["Bumblebee", "Tiger", "Lady bird"], ans: "Bumblebee"}
        ];

        var correctCount = 0;
        var currentQ = 0;

Answer (score 0):

There's more problems with this script but hopefully these small updates help. few tweaks added to show & selects functions

```
 function select(e) {
        if (e.target.textContent == questions[currentQ].ans)
        {
            correctCount++;
            document.getElementById('display').innerHTML= "You win"
        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById('display').innerHTML= "You lose"
        }
        document.getElementById('display').innerHTML += "<p>Score: "+ correctCount;

        // if its the last one
        nextQ();
    }

    function showQ() {
        document.getElementById('questionText').innerHTML = questions[currentQ].text;

        document.getElementById('animalPrint').src = questions[currentQ].img;

        newhtml = "";
        for (var i = 0; i< questions[currentQ].answers.length; i++)
        {
            newhtml+= "<button>"+ questions[currentQ].answers[i] + "</button>";
        }
        document.getElementById('alloptions').innerHTML = newhtml;
        document.getElementById('alloptions').addEventListener('click', select)
    }
```

Comment: i added this to my script and it stayed the same.. I'm sorry i am so new to this